# Why following call is ambiguous?

Tags: c#, .net, ambiguous-call

The following call will fail because compiler expects method `SetAll(PropertyInfo, int)`.

```
var infos = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

var setters = infos.Select(SetAll); // no overload matches delegate.

private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info, object obj) => () => info.SetValue(this, obj);
```

So that means compiler can't use this overload any way. it can't cast `int` to `object`.

Having this in mind, Why the following call is ambiguous?

```
var b = infos.Select(SetAll); // ambiguous between Select<PropertyInfo, int, Action>
                              //              and  Select<PropertyInfo, Action>

private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info, object obj) => () => info.SetValue(this, obj);

private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info) => () => info.SetValue(this, null);
```

If compiler can't use overload with object any way then why its struggling here?

---

Here is the actual code I'm having. I can deal with this problem easily but im just being curios.

```
var infos = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

if (useDefaultsOnReset)
{
    var defaults = infos.Select(GetAll);
    _resetters = infos.Zip(defaults, SetAll).ToArray();
}
else
{
    _resetters = infos.Select(SetAll).ToArray(); // error
}

private object GetAll(PropertyInfo info) => info.GetValue(this);
private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info, object obj) => () => info.SetValue(this, obj);
private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info) => () => info.SetValue(this, null);
```

Comment: Indeed, a [mcve] would make it easier to help you here.

Comment: `(x, i) => SetAll(x, i)` does work. Is it related to that?

Comment: well I want to use overload without object so It would be `(x) => SetAll(x)` but compiler just cant figure it out... wanted to use method groups but .... :P @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `System.Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>` is contravariant in its argument types. This is denoted by the `in` modifier on the corresponding type parameters. What this means is that it is a match for any function taking an argument of type `T1` or any type `T1` can be assigned to, and an argument of type `T2` or any type `T2` can be assigned to. Your first signature matches the overload of `Enumerable.Select` that does not incorporate an index. However, your second signature actually matches the overload of `Enumerable.Select` which does incorporate the index because `int` is assignable to `object`.

To demonstrate this. Simply create an arbitrary class and change your program like so.

```
private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info, A a) => () => info.SetValue(this, obj);
private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info) => () => info.SetValue(this, null);

class A {}
```

You will observe the error disappears as `int` is not assignable to `A`.

As discussed in the comments, there is a wrinkle I failed to take into account. The contravariant relationship holds between reference types and between generics that are not constrained to be value types but it specifically does not work in when directly assigning between delegates taking `int` and `object`
Given

```
Func<int, Action> f;

Func<object, Action> g;
```

The following are *both* errors

```
g = f;
f = g;
```

However, if we replace `int` with say some class `A`

```
Func<A, Action> f;

Func<object, Action> g;
```

The first is an error because an object is not an A, but the second succeeds as explained above.

```
g = f;
f = g;
```

Comment: interestingly covariant works from `Func<object, Action>` to `Func<object, object>` But contravariant does not work. I cant cast `Func<object, Action>` to `Func<int, Action>`? but what you said kinda makes sense to me. (still didn't get it completely) I thought its compiler bug but apparently its not

Comment: The reason you can't perform the second assignment is that this would allow a function which requires an `int` to be passed an `object`. There are languages like Dart which do allow this but it's strictly considered to be unsound. For reference that behavior is called bivariance.

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood. Updating answer with example using variables.

Comment: Very interesting. contravariant  is possible with non-primitive types. for example from `Func<object, Action>` to `Func<MyClass, Action>`... So I think this is something that is prevented by the compiler. but the rule exist when choosing method overloads. thanks Ill look into bivariance too

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with method group you can wrtie dummy variable.

```
private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info, object obj) => () => info.SetValue(this, obj);
private Action SetAll(PropertyInfo info, int _) => () => info.SetValue(this, null); 
//                                           ^ this is dummy but lets you use methodgroup
```

Then this will work

```
infos.Select(SetAll).ToArray();
```

It will use `Select` with indexer but it shouldnt matter much.